# I see that my reputation has migragted from mi.yodeya, but not all of my badges?

Tags: support, migration, reputation, badges

I see that the supporter and teacher badges were migrated, but I also had Enthusiast and Fanatic badges which I don't see now. Are badges re-assigned after migration, according the the data in the migrated site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all badges and reputation scores have been recalculated as a result of the migration.

**UPDATE**

We were able to retroactively apply badge grants for Enthusiast and Fanatic.  You should now see them on your profile.

Comment: I guess that Enthusiast and Fanatic, in particular, just don't translate from one site to the other, since they're based on visit history on the particular site.

Comment: I see them now, thank you!